# How do I join a Minecraft PE server when it says "Invalid or corrupt skin"?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play on a lot of Minecraft PE servers, but since the 0.13.1 update, I try to join some of my favorite servers and it tells me my skin is invalid or corrupt! My skin is perfectly appropriate and I've tried multiple skins. The same thing happens each time.

Comment: Did you remove your custom skin and see if that works? Obviously it thinks there's an issue with it.

Comment: Try downloading the skin again

Comment: Try using the default steve skin

Comment: non elf those have work d

Answer (score 2):

This happens when a player with PE 0.13.0 wants to connect to a server aimed for Pocket Edition version 0.13.1.
You should update the app to 0.13.1 to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to most of the people with 0.13.1 it says invalid or corrupt skin. I saw someone commenting on YouTube that if u have a leet server (like the owner) just restart it but it won't delete your your progress.

Answer (score -3):

Use the Steve or Alex skin maybe that could work or mabey just delete your custum skin and then download it again

Answer (score -3):

Make sure your name doesn't have spaces in it also re download the custom skin if you have one. Also what do you do when the Steve and Alex skin say their invalid or corrupt?!